# Why is the class not set with attr?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following jquery code :

```
function InitVoteContainer(voteContainer) {

    var _userVote = voteContainer.children(".storeUserVote").val();
    var _userObjectId = voteContainer.children(".storeObjectId").val();
    var _userVoteKey = voteContainer.children(".storeVoteKey").val();
    var _UserAuth = voteContainer.children(".storeUserAuth").val();

    var _voteButtonUp = voteContainer.children("div[pid='btUp']");
    var _voteButtonDown = voteContainer.children("div[pid='btDown']");

    var upBtValue = 0;
    var downBtValue = 0;


        _voteButtonUp.attr("class", "upVote_inactive");
        _voteButtonDown.attr("class", "downVote_inactive");

        _voteButtonUp.prop("onclick", null);
        _voteButtonDown.prop("onclick", null);

}
```

The code will switch class on the upVote and downVote buttons. The code runs fine but the classes is never set? the question is why??

Edit 1:

Updates with some more code :

This jquery code runnes at dodument ready

```
function InitVoteControls() {

$("#mainPostList").find(".voteCon").each(function () {
    InitVoteContainer($(this));
});
}
```

And this is the HTML that the jquery is using :

```
<ul id="mainPostList" class="verticalList">
        @foreach (var postViewModel in Model.Posts)
        {
            <li>

<div class="postContainer">

<div class="voteCon">
        <input class="storeUserVote" type="hidden" value="@Model.UserVote" />
        <input class="storeObjectId" type="hidden" value="@Model.ObjectId" />
        <input class="storeVoteKey" type="hidden" value="@Model.VoteKey" />
        <input class="storeUserAuth" type="hidden" value="@Request.IsAuthenticated" />

        @if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <div pid="btUpVote" class="upVote"></div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div pid="btUpVote" class="upVote_inactive"></div>
        }

        <br style="clear:both;" />
        <div class="voteCountBox">
            @Html.Encode(Model.VoteBalance)
        </div>
        <br style="clear:both;" />

        @if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <div pid="btDownVote" class="downVote"></div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div pid="btDownVote" class="downVote_inactive"></div>
        }
</div>
</div>
</li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Comment: `$.attr('class', value)` just works fine. Be sure that your selection is not empty.

Comment: many times people don't think the class is being added, when in reality it is their css that isn't specific enough to see any change

Comment: Added some code, maby its the object I got from voteContainer.children is not correct? How do I check this with Chrome? I can see that it does find a object but Im not sure its the right one.

Comment: `console.log(_voteButtonUp);`, then look in the web dev console.

Comment: Use `div[pid^='btUp']` to select the elements, since the `pid`s are not exactly `'btUp'`, but only start with `'btUp'`.

Comment: or just use the correct pid value such as btUpVote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JavaScript you are selecting your button with

```
voteContainer.children("div[pid='btUp']");
```

which will return an emtpy jQuery object, since you have no div in your markup with the exact attribute `pid='btUp'`. You should use `pid^='btUp'` instead - or directly `pid='btUpVote'`.
See [this example](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) or the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `addClass`

```
_voteButtonUp.addClass("upVote_inactive");
```

Comment: Yes i know, but then I will have to use removeClass as well I supose? I just want to switch class as simple ass possible. Should not attr work for that?

Comment: it should have worked provided that ur selection is not empty try `console.log(_voteButtonUp)` to see if the element to which you want to add class to has been selected

Answer (score 1):

it is really hard to answer this question as we don t have the HTML or how you call the `InitVoteContainer`. But I can assure you the `.attr` function works just fine for 'class' and value.

My first guess is, `voteContainer` parameter be sure it is not null and it s jQuery object use this `$(voteContainer)` if it s not a jQuery object.

The second one is the HTML layout, the children function only works for direct children of the element please check the jQuery doc for that. As you can see from the below using `.find()` can be fiz your issue.

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

Comment: I hava added some code(Edit1). I can also see in the debug that the div I got have the class voteCon so Im probably getting the wrong element, I have switched to find without any luck. But even when having the div element with class voteCon this class should also be changed right?

Answer (score 0):

This should have worked.
Maybe `_voteButtonUp` was not defined. Check your selector.
But, anyway, use `addClass` to do this.

Comment: I have updated my example with more code, take a look and see if you can spot the problem pleas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **addClass()** method in jQuery to achieve the results you're going for.

```
_voteButtonUp.addClass("upVote_inactive");
```

Also, if you use CSS selectors cleverly then you can just do **.addClass('inactive');** in the JS code...

```
#buttonUp .inactive
{
   /* style here */
}
```